# How can I get the days from latest to oldest

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

first time using something like this for assistance so I am not sure if I am doing this correctly but here goes...

I am trying to get my dates to go from the most recent to the oldest. 
When I try Order by [Day] Desc or Asc it doesnt display correctly.

here is a link to my current display as it is right now

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxb3Y.jpg

can anyone help please?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018/03/13'
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 11


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query4 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
             @query5 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 



;with cte as (          
    SELECT 
    CAST(DAY(SentTime) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [Day]
                 --,CAST((DATENAME(DAY, SentTime)) AS INT) as SentDay 
                 ,isnull(count(id),0) 'Total'
                 ,Sum(Case when isnull(IsDeleted,'') <> '' Then 1 else 0 end) Deleted
                 ,Sum(Case when isnull(CallLogTime,'') = '' and isnull(IsDeleted,'')=''  Then 1 else 0 end) 'Not Logged'
                ,Sum(Case when isnull(SentTime,'') = '' and isnull(IsDeleted,'')=''  Then 1 else 0 end) 'Received'
                 ,Sum(Case when isnull(CallLogTime,'') <> '' and isnull(IsDeleted,'')=''  Then 1 else 0 end) Logged

    FROM tblMailItems
    WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, SentTime, GETDATE()) <= @NumDays
    group by DAY(SentTime) --,CAST((DATENAME(DAY, SentTime)) AS INT) 

),
cte2 as (
    select * from cte
)

select * 
into #X
from cte
union
select 'Row Total', sum(Total), sum(Deleted), sum([not logged]), sum(Received), sum(Logged) from cte2

--drop table #X

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Day]) 
                    from #X
                    group by DAY
                    order by DAY asc

                                   FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')

                    --select * from #x 

set @query1 = 'select 1 Sequence, ''Total Logged'' [Description], ' + @cols + '
from 
(
  select [day], total
  from #X
) src
pivot
(
  sum(total)
  for Day in (' + @Cols + ')
) p'



set @query2 = ' UNION select 2 Sequence, ''Deleted'' [Description], ' + @cols + '

from 
(
  select [day], Deleted
  from #X
) src
pivot
(
  sum(Deleted)
  for Day in (' + @Cols + ')
) p'


Select  @query = @query1 + @query2



set @query3 = ' UNION select 3 Sequence, ''Not Logged'' [Description], ' + @cols + ' 
from 
(
  select [day], [Not Logged]
  from #X
) src
pivot
(
  sum([Not Logged])
  for Day in (' + @Cols + ')
) p'

select  @query = @query1 + @query2 + @query3


set @query4 = ' union select 4 sequence, ''Received'' [description], ' + @cols + ' 
from 
(
  select [day], [Received]
  from #x
) src
pivot
(
  sum([Received])
  for day in (' + @cols + ')
) p'

select  @query = @query1 + @query2 + @query3 + @query4


set @query5 = ' UNION select 5 Sequence, ''Logged'' [Description], ' + @cols + ' 
from 
(
  select [day], [Logged]
  from #X
) src
pivot
(
  sum([Logged])
  for Day in (' + @Cols + ')
) p'

select  @query = @query1 + @query2 + @query3 + @query5

execute  (@query)
drop table #x
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Try ordering before you CAST(DAY(SentTime) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [Day]

Comment: You should try to clean up your query in order to fit with your question, not pasting your whole code trying us to solve all your problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering on a `date(time)` column is more efficient, as noted in the comments and answers. I think your problem though, the ordering is taking place on the alias `DAY`, rather than the column `DAY`. Try specifying the column through an alias:

```
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Day]) 
from #X as x 
group by X.DAY 
order by x.DAY asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ORDER BY column, [Day], is cast as VARCHAR(MAX).  Date and times are most efficiently ordered if they are in DATETIME format.